# Scraping Data from a Hockey API with dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, api, dictionary, nested, screen-scraping

I started working on a fun project to better practice my data scraping skills where I am scraping data from an NHL API and trying to record all the positional coordinates of the shots and goals scored (this API will show you any NHL game and has the coordinates and player info for every event that occurred in said game). I am having a problem indexing through the data however, and am really not sure how to approach it. Here is my code below...

```
import requests as rq
import csv

GAME_ID = "2017021121" #Game ID indicates which game I want to look at...first 4 digits is the year, second two the point in season, (01 Pre, 02 Reg, 03 Playoffs, 04 All Star)

#URL to access the coordinates of every event in given game...comes in nested dictionary form
url = f"https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/{GAME_ID}/feed/live"
game = rq.get(url)
#turn the file into a readable one
contents = game.text

#split text into list so we can fool around with it
contents_list = list(csv.reader(contents.splitlines()))

def main():
    file = open( f'coordinates.{GAME_ID}.txt', 'a')
```

What I am trying to do now is to use a for loop to go through the data set and check for "event types" and if they are equal to "shot" or "goal", and if they are to add the values of their x, y coordinates to a dictionary that is printed out into a new file. I have tried indexing through myself, but am not very good at data scraping so I didn't get very far. For reference, here is what the data set looks like (or at least a snippet of it).

```
} ],
        "result" : {
          "event" : "Penalty",
          "eventCode" : "COL162",
          "eventTypeId" : "PENALTY",
          "description" : "Blake Coleman Tripping against Erik Johnson",
          "secondaryType" : "Tripping",
          "penaltySeverity" : "Minor",
          "penaltyMinutes" : 2
        },
        "about" : {
          "eventIdx" : 30,
          "eventId" : 162,
          "period" : 1,
          "periodType" : "REGULAR",
          "ordinalNum" : "1st",
          "periodTime" : "04:47",
          "periodTimeRemaining" : "15:13",
          "dateTime" : "2019-03-17T19:15:33Z",
          "goals" : {
            "away" : 0,
            "home" : 0
          }
        },
        "coordinates" : {
          "x" : -58.0,
          "y" : -37.0
        },
        "team" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "name" : "New Jersey Devils",
          "link" : "/api/v1/teams/1",
          "triCode" : "NJD"
        }
      }, {
        "players" : [ {
          "player" : {
            "id" : 8471233,
            "fullName" : "Travis Zajac",
            "link" : "/api/v1/people/8471233"
          },
          "playerType" : "Winner"
        }, {
          "player" : {
            "id" : 8473544,
            "fullName" : "Derick Brassard",
            "link" : "/api/v1/people/8473544"
          },
          "playerType" : "Loser"
        } ],
        "result" : {
          "event" : "Faceoff",
          "eventCode" : "COL25",
          "eventTypeId" : "FACEOFF",
          "description" : "Travis Zajac faceoff won against Derick Brassard"
        },
        "about" : {
          "eventIdx" : 31,
          "eventId" : 25,
          "period" : 1,
          "periodType" : "REGULAR",
          "ordinalNum" : "1st",
          "periodTime" : "04:47",
          "periodTimeRemaining" : "15:13",
          "dateTime" : "2019-03-17T19:15:59Z",
          "goals" : {
            "away" : 0,
            "home" : 0
          }
        },
        "coordinates" : {
          "x" : -69.0,
          "y" : -22.0
        },
        "team" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "name" : "New Jersey Devils",
          "link" : "/api/v1/teams/1",
          "triCode" : "NJD"
```

To me, it looks like it a bunch of nested dictionaries, but I again I'm not totally sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you!!

Comment: That's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a big list, containing lists of dictionaries. You could iterate through this with a `for-each-loop`.

```
for entry in list:
```

Then, you can look at every entry individually and check if their `eventTypeId` is equal to either `shot` or `goal`:

```
if entry["result"]["eventTypeId"] == "SHOT":
```

And when that's the case, you can pull out the values of the X and Y coordinates like this:

```
x = entry["coordinates"]["x"]
y = entry["coordinates"]["y"]
```

After which you can use those to do whatever you want to do with those coordinates.

Comment: Do I use for entry in list: or... for entry in contents_list: because I am getting errors for both of them

Comment: Replace [list] with the name of your list. You should also consider using `requests.get(url).json()` instead of `.text` (after which you don't have to do the whole `content_list = list(csv...)` thing anymore).

Comment: still getting the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" when I run it...does that mean I can't use the if.... == "SHOT"? Not sure how to get around this.

Comment: That probably means you went 1 layer too deep, try printing what you're doing in the loop (`print(entry)`, `print(entry["result"])`, etc) & look what's going on. That way you should be able to see at what point you're trying to slice a string instead of going through the dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the list, through the desired data into a dictionary to construct the table with pandas.

```
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd

GAME_ID = "2017021121" #Game ID indicates which game I want to look at...first 4 digits is the year, second two the point in season, (01 Pre, 02 Reg, 03 Playoffs, 04 All Star)

#URL to access the coordinates of every event in given game...comes in nested dictionary form
url = f"https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/{GAME_ID}/feed/live"
game = rq.get(url).json()
game = game['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']

rows = []
for each in game:
    if each['result']['event'] in ['Shot','Goal']:
        print(each['result']['event'])
        row = {
                'result':each['result']['event'],
                'x':each['coordinates']['x'],
                'y':each['coordinates']['y']}
        rows.append(row)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
   result     x     y
0    Shot  76.0  -8.0
1    Shot -41.0 -24.0
2    Shot  69.0  -1.0
3    Shot  37.0  30.0
4    Shot -60.0   1.0
5    Goal  43.0 -20.0
6    Shot -85.0   6.0
7    Shot -83.0  11.0
8    Shot -85.0  -5.0
9    Shot  81.0  -1.0
10   Shot -84.0  -7.0
11   Shot -81.0  -3.0
12   Shot -57.0  12.0
13   Shot  74.0 -14.0
14   Goal  64.0   0.0
15   Shot  68.0   2.0
16   Shot  73.0   5.0
17   Shot  63.0  -2.0
18   Shot -26.0 -16.0
19   Shot -84.0  -2.0
20   Shot -74.0  36.0
21   Shot  83.0   6.0
22   Shot -88.0   7.0
23   Shot -39.0  30.0
24   Shot -69.0 -22.0
25   Shot  65.0  32.0
26   Shot  80.0  -3.0
27   Shot -70.0  -6.0
28   Shot -87.0  17.0
29   Shot -29.0 -20.0
..    ...   ...   ...
47   Shot  81.0   1.0
48   Shot -82.0   0.0
49   Shot  38.0 -28.0
50   Shot  66.0  -9.0
51   Shot  49.0   5.0
52   Shot -48.0 -12.0
53   Shot  39.0  20.0
54   Goal  75.0  -9.0
55   Shot -84.0  -7.0
56   Shot  88.0 -28.0
57   Shot  41.0 -20.0
58   Shot -41.0  12.0
59   Shot  40.0   7.0
60   Shot  72.0  -4.0
61   Goal  86.0   7.0
62   Shot -77.0  -8.0
63   Shot  34.0 -32.0
64   Shot -79.0 -10.0
65   Shot  61.0   6.0
66   Shot -43.0  17.0
67   Shot -41.0  -5.0
68   Shot -35.0  19.0
69   Shot -45.0 -11.0
70   Shot -77.0  -8.0
71   Shot  80.0  -1.0
72   Shot -87.0   7.0
73   Shot  84.0  24.0
74   Shot  76.0   7.0
75   Goal  83.0 -18.0
76   Shot -81.0  -5.0

[77 rows x 3 columns]
```